# Is there a way to pass timeout parameter in sign in function of devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to sign in as another user, but I want that session automatically expire after some time like 5 minutes.

But my default expire time is 1 hour which I set in devise.rb as

```
config.timeout_in = 1.hour
```

Forexample I have a user list.
one is test@test.com
another is test2@test.com

I am logged in as test@test.com.
Now I want to login as test2@test.com,
so I will sign out, and then sign as as

```
sign_out
```

`sign_in (:user, test_user_2)`

But since my original account is test@test.com, and I am just logging in as test2@test.com for development purpose, I want that the session automatically timeout after some time (like 5 minutes) instead of 1 hour by default.

Is there a way to pass timeout parameter in the sign in function of devise ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit difficult to do. You can dynamically set timeout_in the users model by overriding the def timeout_in Devise method.

```
# You could add a boolean onto the user if testing and set it to true once signed in with a testing user. 
# You can then somehow set it to false once the user signs out after testing a user. 

def timeout_in
  if self.testing?
    5.minutes 
  else
    30.minutes 
  end
end
```

Another workaround to this problem, although it doesn't answer your question directly would be to allow the previous admin the ability to resign into his previous account whenever he/she is done with testing. You could set a session[:admin_logged_in] with the previous user's id when becoming another user. If session[:admin_logged_in] is present you could create a route to make the user an admin again and sign out the testing user. After the user becomes an admin user again you could just clear the session[:admin_logged_in].

```
def become_other_user
  session[:admin_logged_in] = current_user.id
  sign_out current_user
  user = User.find(params[:id])
  sign_in(:user, user, { :bypass => true })
  redirect_to something_path
end


def become_admin_user
  if session[:admin_logged_in].present?
    if current_user
      admin_user = User.find_by_id(session[:admin_logged_in])
      sign_out current_user
      sign_in(:user, admin_user, { :bypass => true })
      session[:admin_logged_in].clear 
      flash.clear if flash.present?
    end
  end
end

# erb nav file 

<% if session[:admin_logged_in].present? %>
  <%= link_to 'Switch To Admin', become_admin_user_path, class: '#' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for this info David,  I was curious, btw Isn't there some device method which can be overridden ? where devise checks if session is present or not?